# Confusion about class selectors

Tags: css-selectors

I'm new to CSS and am not entirely to sure how if I understand how classes work. Why is that even though I'm modifying the color of text for `.testClass` the change also applies to text in `testClassing`?

[image: testClass is within body and testClassing within section]

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Post the code as text, properly formatted into a snippet

Comment: All visible content should be contained within the `<body>` tags. Your HTML is therefore syntactically incorrect. I think the browser is automatically putting your `.testClassing` within the body, which would inherit the color from your body of class `testClass`. Note that `color` is an inherited CSS property.

Comment: Also note conventional classnames `use-hyphenation` as oppposed to `camelCase`

Comment: Your meta tag should not have the slash at the beginning, rather at the end

Comment: Use https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Pseudo elements use two colons `::` not one